# Lion Man helping two kids in adventures

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember one old movie.
I watched it in some '90s, so it can be from those years or maybe even the '80s. I don't remember it in color, so maybe it's black and white.

It's something about two kids, brother and sister I think. They going through some adventures and there is a Lion Man who helps them. He is not always with them; they always have to call him for help. The Lion Man in my memory looks similar to the Lion from The Wizard of Oz. It's a man with a lion head. And I remember when he comes to help those kids he broker some walls. And I also remember that in the background of credits, was the wall with a lion ornament on it.
Very possible that this is a tv show.

For sure it's not:
The Wizard of Oz, Narnia movies, Old Narnia tv show, Beauty and the Beast (1987)...

Comment: CS Lewis' The Lon the Witch and the Wardrobe also had a lion as a leading character, though there were four children involved rather than two.. There is certainly a tv version now but I can't say whether that existed at the time you saw yours.